# Is there a way to fix the fall through error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-2.8.10/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:71:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-5.7.7/lib/src/platform_interface/utils/load_bundle_task_state.dart:13:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'.
      throw FallThroughError();
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

This is the error I'm getting when trying to run my application.

This error started happening only after I connected my app to firebase. And I can't get what it means.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the versions of firebase plugins might be incompatible. `firebase_core-1.24.0` seems to be a little old, please try upgrading your packages to their latest versions.

You can do major version upgrades with this command:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade#upgrading-packages)